# Is it possible to send Vue/Javascript code within an object to another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a parent and child `Vue` components. The child component supplies the parent component with data required to render the page using a simple object that is emitted using `emit`.

Child component data:

```
   const Steps [
      {
            sequence: 1,
            name: "Personal",
            description: `<p>Enter your name and phone number</p>`,
          },
      {
            sequence: 2,
            name: "OTP",
            description: `<p>An OTP code has been sent to you. Resend code</p>`,
          },
    ]

const SelectedStep = ref( 0 ); // Which step did you select?
const ActiveStep = ref( {} );  // What step is the form currently on?


SelectedStep.value += 1; // e.g. SelectedStep.value === 2

// Get the object in Steps array where the sequence === 2
ActiveStep.value = Steps.find(step => {
        return step.sequence === SelectedStep.value
      })

// Send this to the parent to render the description and title
emit('SelectedStep', ActiveStep.value);
```

Depending on which `sequence` is selected, the object within `Steps` matching that sequence value will get loaded into `ActiveStep`. This is then emitted/supplied to the parent component.

However if you look at the object with `sequence: 2` above, within the `description` is a `resend code` text. I need that to be a link with a binding so that when it is clicked a function is run to resend the code. I imagined something like this:

```
{
        sequence: 2,
        name: "OTP",
        description: `<p>An OTP code has been sent to you. <a v-on:click="resendOTP">Resend code</a></p>`,
      },
```

When that is rendered on the page, the `v-on:click` is not being interpreted and is rendered as-is in the HTML.

The parent component is just a view that uses this component:

```
    <header>
    <h1>{{ActiveStep.title}}</h1>
    <div v-html="`${ActiveStep.description}`">{{ActiveStep.description}}</div>
    </header>
    <div>
          <div class="content">
            <Component-Signup v-on:SelectedStep="updateActiveStep"/>
          </div>
       </div> 
    
    <script>
    import ComponentSignup from "../../components/Signup.vue"
    
    export default {
    components: {
    "Component-Signup": ComponentSignup
  },
    setup() {
    const ActiveStep = ref({});
        
    function updateActiveStep(SelectedStep) {
          ActiveStep.value = SelectedStep // SelectedStep is the object emitted from child component
         }
    
    return {
          updateActiveStep,
          ActiveStep
        }
    }
}
    </script>
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: you'd have to post the parent component to see what it's doing wrong with the emitted data it receives - are you using `v-html` property? hmmm, no, not quite ... because then you'd be *trying to compose templates using v-html* which won't work - I think you need to re-think your design - it's not common for child components to be sending such data to a parent

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated the question with the parent component. The design is as such because the child component is a signup form which may be placed on a normal view page or it may be in a modal.  The parent layout may be different .e.g a modal will have different padding widths etc than a normal page hence I thought the form should be a resusable component and the parent can deal with titles and descriptions. Is that a bad approach?

Answer (score 1):

First, your `description` contains HTML, so interpolation (`{{ }}`) will not display it as you expect ...it will be displayed encoded

`v-html` directive can be used to render [raw HTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

**BUT** `v-html` is useful ONLY for HTML. Any Vue related functionality (as `v-on`) will not work. Docs:

> Note that you cannot use `v-html` to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition.

Your only option is to create separate component for each step, and use [is](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is) to display the right component for the current step...

Comment: but where would the header information reside? if I create a component for each step, the code for `resend code` etc will have to reside in the parent component. That makes it difficult to resuse the form elsewhere like in a modal for example. If I need to change the title or description, I'd have to change it in all the views.

Comment: Just place the resend code in the `OtpStepComponent`. Pass any title/header to the component as prop